# Shared state in a XCTestCase class?

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing

Can I have shared states in a XCTestCase class?

```
class Tests: XCTestCase {
    var person: Person!
    
    override func setUp() {
        person = Person()
    }
    override func tearDown() {
        person = nil
    }
    func testExample() {
        print("✅ testExample")
        print(person)
        XCTAssertTrue(true)
    }
    
    func testExample2() {
        print("✅ testExample2")
        print(person)
        XCTAssertTrue(true)
    }
}
```

For example in the above code I know that person object is different in the different test methods, but is it possible to have same memory location for person object in both the test methods?

Comment: It's possible (just use a global variable or static variable), but you shouldn't do it. Unit tests should be independent, so they can run in isolation, in parallel, and in any order.

Comment: Can you please show me an example?

Comment: BTW this whole setup/teardown can be removed, and you can just use `var person = Person()`

Comment: Show you what, an example of a global variable? That feels unclean to suggest, haha. You shouldn't do it. Let me take a different approach: why do you think you need to share state between test cases?

Comment: You would just make a class variable. But don't. If one test method depends in some way on the action of another, you're doing it wrong. Tests should (and can) run successfully in random order.

Comment: @Alexander Not the teardown. The teardown needs to be there; otherwise Person objects will accumulate, one per test, until the entire testing done.

Comment: @matt Oh, do the test case objects live for the full test run, even once they've completed all their test methods?

Comment: @Alexander Yeah. Little-known but really important fact. I've put it into an answer so that we'll have something to refer to henceforth.

Answer (score 3):

There are many popular misconceptions or confusions about how tests work, so I'll just take this opportunity to set the record straight. The memory is managed in a really weird way:

**Every time a test *method* runs, a *brand-new instance* of the test case *class* is created, and that instance *stays in existence* until *all* the test methods of *every* test case class have finished.**

Thus, you don't need to create the Person object for the `person` instance variable before every test method (`setUp`), because you'll get a whole new Tests instance and thus a whole new Person object, before every test method, if you just say

```
    var person: Person! = Person()
```

But you *do* need your `tearDown` to nilify the `person` instance variable after each test method, because otherwise you'll end up with lots of Person objects. That might not matter for a tiny Person but it's a good habit to get into because you can use a boatload of memory without realizing it otherwise.